# Set Selected Items Without Triggering OnItemSelectedListener

Tags: android

I have been struggling with this for days now, I have a list of items I am loading from my server.  When the items are loaded I display the list and I set the selected item for each spinner.  Now these are my problems.

Case 1:
The onItemSelectedListener for each item in my adapter gets triggered on page load.

So I did some research online and decided to use a variable to check the state.  When the view is created I set firstTime to true in the on click listener like this:

```
viewHolder.spStatus.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if (!firstTime) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            builder.setTitle("Confirm");
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to change this?");

            builder.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    int selectedPosition = Integer.parseInt(viewHolder.id.getTag().toString());
                    String selectedId = viewHolder.id.getText().toString();
                    updateStatus(selectedPosition, selectedId,
                            ((ArrayAdapter<String>) viewHolder.spStatus.getAdapter())
                                    .getItem(selectedPosition));
                }

            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Do nothing
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }

        firstTime = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do Nothing
    }
});
```

Now this is what happens when I do this it's either when I scroll the onItemSelected change listener fires depending on where I put `firstTime=false` or when I filter the list I have to tap twice before the event is triggered.

Comment: This is very frustrating, spent days on this, guess I'm just going to switch to a radio button list.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this,

```
    public void setSelection(int position, boolean animate, boolean noTrigger, OnItemSelectedListener onItemSelectedListener) {
    if(noTrigger) {
        Log.e("SET_SELECTION", "No trigger at position " + position);
        this.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
    }

    super.setSelection(position, animate);
    this.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            setOnItemSelectedListener(onItemSelectedListener);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a `ViewHolder` with an `itemView` which contains a `Spinner`. You want to be able to set the selected position of the `Spinner` programmatically without triggering the `OnItemSelectedListener` of the `Spinner`.

Right now you are using an anonymous `OnItemSelectedListener`. If you make this listener a field of the `ViewHolder` class

```
private OnItemSelectedListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
    // listener code goes here
    // ...
    };
```

... then you can "unset" the listener before setting the selected position programmatically and "reset" it afterwards like the following method shows:

```
private void setPosition(int position){
    if(listener != null){
        spinner.setOnItemClickListener(null);
    }
    spinner.setSelection(position);
    spinner.setOnItemClickListener(listener);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution for RecyclerView Adapter in Kotlin

```
class DataAdapter(myData: ArrayList<MyData>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.DataHolder>(){


    override fun onViewRecycled(holder: DataHolder){
        holder.mSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = null   //remove listener when item is out of view
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
    }
    
    
    class DataHolder(itemView: View, private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        
        val mSpinner: Spinner = itemView.findViewById(R.id.spinner)
        
        fun bind(data: MyData){
            
            var pass = false // variable to check first run
            val adapter = SpinnerAdapter(context)
            mSpinner.adapter = adapter
            
            val onSelectListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
                override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {

                }


                override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, p1: View?, p2: Int, p3: Long) {
                    
                    if (pass){
                        // actions onSelected
                    }
                    pass = true

                }

            }
            
            mSpinner.setSelection(3)    //the onItemSelected will be triggered when the item is first created
            mSpinner.onItemSelectedListener = onSelectListener
        
        }
    
    }
}
```